# How to cut line in a face without Knife?

Tags: modeling

I have this square and I want to make cut along the green lines.

[image]

The problem is, I try to use the knife tool (K+C) and the proper camera angling to connect the vertices and the edge, but the knife wont cut.

I want to be able to "loop divide" (line?) the face and drag a line so I can line the needed line to it's location. Or, atleast get the knife tool working properly.

How can I do this?

Comment: This looks like a case that knife tool should support - could you provide a Blend file?

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to cut four squares at the corners of the front face or cut the side faces from the back corner to the front edge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knife *should* work for this:

[image]

I suspect the darker face on the right is the result of a second, super-imposed face which is preventing the knife tool from working. To fix it, delete the face or use <kbd>W</kbd>*> Remove Doubles*:

[image]

That said, there might be a faster way to get the desired result, for example *Subdivide* and *Bevel*:

[image]

I also used triangulate (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>) at the end; not sure if those diagonal edges were desired or not.